# android fast pixel access and manipulation

Tags: android, image, android-canvas, draw, pixel

I'm trying to port an emulator that i have written in java to android. Things have been going nicely, I was able to port most of my codes with minor changes however due to how emulation works, I need to render image at pixel level.

As for desktop java I use

```
int[] pixelsA = ((DataBufferInt) src.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

which allow me to get the reference to the pixel buffer and update it on the fly(minimize object creations)

Currently this is what my emulator for android does for every frame

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixelsA, 256, 192, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    canvas.drawBitmap(buffer, 0, 0, null);

}
```

pixelsA is an array int[], pixelsA contains all the colour informations, so every frame it will have to create a bitmap object by doing

```
buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixelsA, 256, 192, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

which I believe is quite expensive and slow.

Is there any way to draw pixels efficiently with canvas?

Comment: True, createBitmap is slow, it is memory copy, and even conversion of pixel format in your case!

Answer (score 11):

One quite low-level method, but working fine for me (with native code):

Create `Bitmap` object, as big as your visible screen.
Also create a `View` object and implement `onDraw` method.

Then in native code you'd load libjnigraphics.so native library, lookup functions `AndroidBitmap_lockPixels` and `AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels`.
These functions are defined in Android source in bitmap.h.

Then you'd call lock/unlock on a bitmap, receiving address to raw pixels. You must interpret RGB format of pixels accordingly to what it really is (16-bit 565 or 32-bit 8888).

After changing content of the bitmap, you want to present this on screen.
Call `View.invalidate()` on your `View`. In its `onDraw`, blit your bitmap into given `Canvas`.

This method is very low level and dependent on actual implementation of Android, however it's very fast, you may get 60fps no problem.

bitmap.h is part of Android NDK since platform version 8, so this IS official way to do this from Android 2.2.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [drawBitmap method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) that avoids creating a Bitmap each time, or even as a last resort, draw the pixels one by one with [drawPoint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPoint%28float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Comment: I tried drawBitmap method that takes int[] as its parameter, it gives nice performance boost over bitmap object creation. It seems to be the only way(I think) to achieve acceptable performance without resorting  to native code.

Comment: Good to know it worked. As you say there's nothing as fast as going native, but it is a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate the bitmap every single time. Try something like this:

```
Bitmap buffer = null;
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if(buffer == null) buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 192, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    buffer.copyPixelsFromBuffer(pixelsA);
    canvas.drawBitmap(buffer, 0, 0, null);
}
```

EDIT: as pointed out, you need to update the pixel buffer. And the bitmap must be mutable for that to happen.

Comment: This won't work. Bitmap initializes its own pixel buffer in createBitmap, not calling it will not update Bitmap's pixels.

Answer (score 0):

if pixelsA is already an array of pixels (which is what I would infer from your statement about containing colors) then you can just render them directly without converting with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(pixelsA, 0, 256, 0, 0, 256, 192, false, null);
```