# Android using images created during runtime as backgrounds

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing, pixel

so I have a regular drawable that I want to use with many variations.  I plan to replace certain pixel colors with specific variations.  To reduce the amount of image files required for the app, I plan to do such pixel-manipulation during runtime.  Can I create a drawable/background resource to be used, during runtime?  Or is that impossible on Android?  Like I start with a .png file, and during runtime I modd it into a similar .png file.  Can I use that new .png file as a background for a layout, while the program is still going?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a new .png file everytime. Please have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593810/android-fast-pixel-access-and-manipulation). The first answer provides a way to manipulate a bitmap object pixelwise during runtime. So you start with a .png file which is provided by your app and get a bitmap out of it by doing this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap_resource);
```

Then you can manipulate the bitmap and change the background again. If you want you can save it as a .png too by using:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outStream);
```

Have a look at the documentation for Bitmap [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Comment: hmmm thanks. your link seems to be a good start. the difficulty is that i'm not sure how to use the new PNG or bitmap as a background for a view's layout file, at runtime

Comment: BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
view.setBackground(bd);

Of course view has to be the view which should get the background. And it has to be initialized before.